# Group and summarize matrix by value

Tags: python, numpy

I have two matrices, `prob` and `totalHigh` both of shape `axbxcxd`. `a` and `b` are coordinates. Here are two samples:

```
In [77]: prob[1,1,:]
Out[77]: 
array([[ 0.09,  0.01,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ],
       [ 0.81,  0.09,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ],
       [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ]])

In [78]: totalHigh[1,1,:]
Out[78]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]])
```

`totalHigh` contains information about outcomes, unfortunately on two dimensions. Correspondingly, `prob` contains probabilities of these outcomes. For example, the total probability of outcome `1`, at coordinates `1,1` is `0.01+0.81`.

How can I remove the redundant dimension?

#### Expected Outcome

```
simplifiedHigh[1,1,:]
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
simplifiedProb[1,1,:]
array([0.09, 0.82, 0.09, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

How do I get that *in the most efficient way*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`np.bincount`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) and [`np.unique`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html) -

```
IDs = np.unique(totalHigh_sliced)
counts = np.bincount(totalHigh_sliced.ravel(),prob_sliced.ravel())
```

Sample run -

```
In [215]: prob_sliced
Out[215]: 
array([[ 0.09,  0.01,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ],
       [ 0.81,  0.09,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ],
       [ 0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ]])

In [216]: totalHigh_sliced
Out[216]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
       [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [2, 3, 4, 5, 6]])

In [217]: IDs = np.unique(totalHigh_sliced)
     ...: counts = np.bincount(totalHigh_sliced.ravel(),prob_sliced.ravel())
     ...: 

In [218]: IDs
Out[218]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6])

In [219]: counts
Out[219]: array([ 0.09,  0.82,  0.09,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ,  0.  ])
```

Comment: I was about to submit the same answer :P An alternative option would be using [binned_statistics](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.binned_statistic.html), but as the OPs only wants the sum, `bincount` is probably faster.

Comment: @imaluengo Yeah `bincount` from my experience is quite fast indeed!

Comment: Would there be an efficient way to do this for the whole matrix or do I have to iterate over the first two dimensions?

Comment: @FooBar Do you have the same `totalHigh[1,1,:]` across the first two axes/dimensions? If not, I think iterating would make sense.

Comment: @Divakar What if actually it were to be the same?

Comment: @FooBar Well in that case, you can use [`np.add.reduceat`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.reduceat.html) in a vectorized manner for the entire array.